# Redirect a subdomain to an empty subdirectory

Tags: redirect, blogger, http-redirect

I have a blog which is hosted on myblog.blogger.com. I managed to redirect it to blog.mydomain.com.

However, I want users to access my bog under the URL: www.mydomain.com/blog. i.e. if a user types blog.mydomain.com, the url will become www.mydomain.com/blog, but the actual blog is hosted on myblog.blogger.com.

To reword the question in another way: is it possible to redirect myblog.blogger.com to www.mydomain.com/blog, where the actually blog is hosted on myblog.blogger.com?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly, you are using blogger.com, and i dont believe that there is a need to redirect anything, you just specify your domain name in blogger.com 
check the following link http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs

Comment: It seems that I can only specify a **subdomain** name such as `blog.mydomain.com`, rather than something like `www.mydomain.com/blog`. What I want is later.

Answer (score 0):

Blogger.com doesn't support hosting the blog on subdirectories as of yet. You can only use a subdomain or www.

Comment: Is this an answer or meant to be comment